# SQL Server : SELECT when 2 values exist in rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL query result

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | C1 |
| A1 | C2 |
| A2 | C1 |
| A3 | C1 |
| A3 | C2 |

This is the SQL

```
SELECT 
    col1, col2 
FROM 
    table 
WHERE 
    col2 = 'C1' OR col2 = 'C2' 
GROUP BY 
   col1, col2
```

Now the question is, how can I get a result where col2 must have both C1 and C2 values, like this (As you can see the A2 is not in the list, since it doesn't have the 'C2' unlike the 'A1' and 'A3')

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | C1 |
| A1 | C2 |
| A3 | C1 |
| A3 | C2 |

Update :
If col1 and col2 are from 2 table

```
SELECT  
    table.col1, table2.col2  
FROM  
    table  
INNER JOIN   
    table2  
ON  
    table2.col3 = table.col3  
WHERE  
    table2.col2 = 'C1'  
OR  
    table2.col2 = 'C2'  
GROUP BY  
    table.col1, table2.col2
```

Comment: If there was a `C3` value, would you expect that to be returned too?

Comment: A2 is out because it only have C1.

Comment: can you try with in operator  like col2 in ('C1', 'C2') and having clause

Comment: @Ajay2707 That's only if you want to look at single rows, whereas the OP wants to evaluate groups of rows.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this if you are using MySQL 8+:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, MIN(col2) OVER (PARTITION BY col1) min_col2,
              MAX(col2) OVER (PARTITION BY col1) max_col2
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT col1, col2
FROM cte
WHERE min_col2 = 'C1' AND max_col2 = 'C2';
```

Note that this answers assumes that `C1` and `C2` are the only two possible values for `col2`.  If there could be *other* values, then the above logic would have to change slightly.

Comment: Sorry.  Fixed.  Let's let the OP drop comments on our answers now.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
select col1, col2 
from t 
where col1 in (
  select col1 from t where col2 in ('C1', 'C2') group by col1 
  having count(distinct col2) = 2
)
order by col1, col2
```

Comment: This doesn't work if a group has two `C1` values and no `C2` values.

Comment: @Dai Yes, but the case you mention is not valid according to the question.

Comment: The OP didn't say that `col2` values were guaranteed to be distinct. Where are you seeing that?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, that's much better.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to determine which groups of rows (grouped by `col1`) have both `C1` and `C2` present - there are many ways to do that but one approach is to `GROUP BY col1` and use `COUNT` for `'C1'` and `'C2'` separately (not together, because I assume a group could have two `'C1'` values and zero `'C2'` values) - then do an `INNER JOIN` on `col1` in valid groups, like so:

```
SELECT
    t.*
FROM
    tbl AS t
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            col1
        FROM
            tbl
        GROUP BY
            col1
        HAVING
            COUNT( CASE WHEN col2 = 'C1' THEN 1 END ) >= 1
            AND
            COUNT( CASE WHEN col2 = 'C2' THEN 1 END ) >= 1
    ) AS q ON t.col1 = q.col1
```

---

#### Update:

The OP posted a comment reply with this query (below) and asked how to use the above technique with it:

```
SELECT
    table.col1,
    table2.col2
FROM
    table
    INNER JOIN table2 on table2.col3 = table.col3
WHERE
    table2.col2 = 'C1'
    OR
    table2.col2 = 'C2'
GROUP BY
    table.col1,
    table2.col2
```

The solution is to use a CTE because that query's results will need to be used twice (because we do an `INNER JOIN` on itself):

```
WITH cte AS
(
    -- This is the original query the OP provided in the comment reply. It is unmodified.
    SELECT
        table.col1,
        table2.col2
    FROM
        table
        INNER JOIN table2 on table2.col3 = table.col3
    WHERE
        table2.col2 = 'C1'
        OR
        table2.col2 = 'C2'
    GROUP BY
        table.col1,
        table2.col2
    --
)
SELECT
    t.*
FROM
    cte AS t
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            col1
        FROM
            cte
        GROUP BY
            col1
        HAVING
            COUNT( CASE WHEN col2 = 'C1' THEN 1 END ) >= 1
            AND
            COUNT( CASE WHEN col2 = 'C2' THEN 1 END ) >= 1
    ) AS q ON t.col1 = q.col1
```

Comment: SELECT 
    table.col1, table2.col2 
FROM 
    table INNER JOIN table2 on table2.col3 = table.col3
WHERE 
    table2.col2 = 'C1' OR table2.col2 = 'C2' 
GROUP BY 
   table.col1, table2.col2 ,how to implement if there are some level of inner join table?

Comment: @UqubeSdnBhd I don't understand your question (what do you mean by "some level of inner join table"?).Also, the SQL you posted in your comment is incorrect - I don't know why you posted it.

Comment: how to use your method in the sql i posted in the previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function `count` as follows:

```
Select col1, col2 from
(Select col1, col2,
       Count(distinct col2) over (partition by col1) as cnt
  From t
 Where col2 in ('C1', 'C2')) t
Where cnt = 2;
```

You can also use `exists` as follows:

```
Select col1, col2 
  From t
 Where t.col2 in ('C1', 'C2')
   And exists (select 1 from t tt
                Where tt.col1 = t.col1
                  And tt.col2 in ('C1', 'C2')
                  And t.col2 <> tt.col2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are no duplicate rows, I would recommend window functions:

```
select col1, col2
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when col2 in ('C1', 'C2') then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by col1) as cnt
     from t
    ) t
Where cnt = 2;
```

Note:  This works even when `col2` has values other than the two mentioned.  And in that case, it returns *all* the rows.

This is how I interpret the question.

You can also phrase this using subqueries in the `where` clause.  One method uses `exists`:

```
select col1, col2
from t t1
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.col1 = t1.col1 and t2.col2 = 'C1'
             ) and
      exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.col1 = t1.col1 and t2.col2 = 'C2'
             ) ;
```

This will work with duplicates as well as with other columns.  I prefer `exists` but you can express this also as:

```
select col1, col2
from t t1
where (select count(distinct t2.col2)
       from t t2
       where t2.col1 = t1.col1 and
             t2.col2 in ('C1', 'C2')
      ) = 2;
```